# How to return to current working directory after cdin'g out in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file and I want to do the following...

```
cd C:\some\directory
some_command.cmd
# return to the directory I started in here
python some_script.py
```

As you can see in the commented line, I need some way to return to the directory I started in.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set OLDDIR=%CD% rem current directory

rem your script 

chdir /d %OLDDIR% rem go to OLDDIR
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried this.  I have an echo statement at the end of my .cmd script that outputs, but it never switches back to the olddir.  I put an echo between the .cmd call and the chdir call, and that echo never printed.  Weird

Comment: You should call @echo off at the begin of script, or try the pushd and popd this is better way.

Comment: Why are pushd and popd better?  "pushd /" and "popd" afterward don't seem to wrk.

Comment: pushd C:\some\directory some_command.cmd popd, it is better because you in one step memorize and go to the location, with out additional path variable

Answer (score 7):

You can try pushd and popd commands 
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd

Comment: This also works with UNC paths it is way better than cd.  To see what directories you have on the stack just type pushd and the list will be displayed.